# Collapsible box not responding in navbarPage

Tags: r, shiny, box, shinyjs, shinythemes

[image]I'm currently developing a compact R Shiny application, but I've encountered an issue where the collapsible boxes fail to collapse upon clicking. Despite attempting different solutions, the problem persists. I would greatly appreciate assistance in resolving this matter.

Furthermore, I'm interested in learning how to customize the visual appearance of these boxes (the solidHeader and Collapsible parameters); Specifically, I'd like the boxes of my navbarPage ("Comparizon table" and "Closing price chart") to collapse when clicking the '-' button.

Below is a minimal example for reference:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shiny)
library(quantmod)
library(DT)
library(highcharter)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinythemes)  

# I using getSymbols to retrieve data
the_data <- getSymbols("AAPL", src = "yahoo", from = "2018-11-07", to = Sys.Date(), auto.assign = FALSE)
# The keep only the "Adjusted Close" as time serie
Prix_de_cloture <- Cl(the_data)

#My UI part
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(""),
  navbarPage(
    "Clusters de Volatilité",
    header = tagList(
      useShinydashboard()
    ),
    inverse = TRUE,
    theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    shinyjs::inlineCSS(
      ".main-sidebar { background-color: #f8f9fa; }"
    ),
    tabPanel("Analyses primaires",
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(align = "center",
                            selectInput("ticker", "Choisir un Ticker :", c("AAPL", "MSFT", "GOOGL", "AMZN")),
                            dateRangeInput("date", strong("Choisir les dates"),
                                           start = "2020-01-06", end = (Sys.Date()-1))
               ),
               mainPanel(
                 fluidRow(
                   # DT Table
                   box(title = "Comparizon table",
                       status = "primary",
                       solidHeader = TRUE,
                       collapsible = TRUE,
                       DTOutput("Comparizontable"),
                       width = 12,
                       height = 'auto'),
                   br(), br(),

                   # Highchart
                   box(title = "Closing price chart",
                       status = "primary",
                       solidHeader = TRUE,
                       collapsible = TRUE,
                       highchartOutput("closing_price"),
                       width = 12,
                       height = 'auto')
                 )
               )
             )
    )
  ))
```

The server part

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$Comparizontable <- renderDataTable({
    info.mat <- structure(c(9.342, 9.354, 9.342, 9.347, 9.344, 9.36, 9.344, 9.35,
                            9.349, 9.369, 9.349, 9.356, 9.37, 9.39, 9.37, 9.378, 9.345, 9.365,
                            9.345, 9.353), dim = 4:5, dimnames = list(c("Akaike", "Bayes",
                                                                        "Shibata", "Hannan-Quinn"), c("Arch(1,1)", "GARCH(1,1)", "TGARCH(1,1)",
                                                                                                      "EGARCH(1,1)", "GJR-GARCH(1,1)")))
    datatable(info.mat, escape = FALSE)
  })

  output$closing_price <- renderHighchart({
    # Trying to plot the graph
    hchart(the_data)
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Shiny output]

Comment: Your example is not reproducible, you should edit it. There are at least several packages missing (functions `getSymbols`, `useShinydashboard()`, also the `shiny` package, ...). Also you should clarify what you mean by "customize the appearance". Multiple questions in one post should be avoided.

Comment: Sorry is added their packages (quantmod, shiny and shinyWidgets). The example is now reproducible. Specifically,
I'd like the boxes of my navbarPage ("Comparizon table" and "Closing price chart") to collapse when clicking the '-' button.